# calling java jar library from google script

Tags: java, google-apps-script

Is it possible to call a java jar library from google script. If yes, how is this best done. Where would the jar and the jvm need to be located.

thank you,

Daniel

Comment: It looks like one, rather elaboate, approach, is to use google apps engine. It seems to support a number of language environments including java. So, i guess one way could be to sign up and create a java app with a rest api wrapper around the jar classes, and then access that from within sheets google scripts.

Sounds like a lot of work, but at least it seems doable in theory. Perhaps there is a simpler way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Apps Script provides an isolated execution environment for Javascript with built-in APIs for interacting with various Google services.

Interaction with external resources is primarily through either the [URLFetch service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/) (for making HTTP requests) and the [JBDC service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/jdbc/) (for database system connectivity). [The External APIs guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external) provides a quick overview of interacting with APIs using the URLFetch service.

So, your observation is correct. To make something available for interaction in the Apps Script environment, you'd need to stand up an API available via HTTP.